# Adding overlay image in ImageView

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am using picasso library to load images from url to ImageView,

```
Picasso.with(activityContext).load(thumbnailurl)
                .into(imageViewReference);
```

Can I set background image of ImageView (Not the source Image), using Picasso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use callback of `picasso`.However you can't use `setBackgroundResource` because it's always takes int as parameter and you will get bitmap in return from picasso.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url).into(new Target() {
    @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
        imageView.setBackground(d);
    }
    @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }
    @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(), bitmap1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

if you have to set one image over another the same task i have done by using transparent image from drawable and another one is getting from sdcard,using this code it works,you have to just pass your images bitmap in this method()...

Comment: It's very generic. Although it solves the problem of overlaying images, it doesn't explain how to implement this when using Picasso.